# Searching for subrow in an array

Tags: swift

I have a problem with swift. I want to search an array of strings consists of 3 different elements filling this array in certain manner. Next i want to search the array for a subset of 3 particular strings next to each other and return their indexes. Is that a special array method for this?

Copied from comment:
Assumed i have an Int array like [1,2,1,3,2]. I want to search it for a subarray [1,2,1] and return indexes of those elements. Should i use findwithPredicate method?

Comment: You need to be more specific including the code you have written and are having trouble with along with input and output data examples. Add that and the question could be re-opened, (Soon to be closed as-is).

Comment: Assumed i have an Int array like [1,2,1,3,2]. I want to search it for a subarray [1,2,1] and return indexes of those elements. Should i use findwithPredicate method?

Comment: It is best to add new information the the question. I did that for you in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would just iterate the Array checking for matches.

Check the items in the array in sequence comparing the current item with the first item of the subarray. If it does not match move on. If it does start comparing the rest of the subarray, if it fails go bad to scanning the array.